# TypeError: $.post is not a function

Tags: jquery, post, firebug

I am getting the above error when trying to do a .post method call using the console in firebug.

My application is built in flash, which does a search based on the filters selected.I copied one of the post calls from the net tab in firebug and edited it to see what a different call would return.On doing a $.post from the console tab with the edited string it is giving the above error.
On doing jquery.post it says that "jquery is not defined".

The edited string is "syntactically" correct.

Can anyone help me by telling how to do a post call using console with a custom string.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I don't have access to edit the code written initially to get the current application.
All I can do is see the files it loads from which it drives the whole application.

Comment: You are loading jQuery, are you?

Comment: Check you have add jquery library in your code

Comment: also by default unless you specify a `noConflict()` jquery uses `$.` instead of `jQuery.` (or has been such the case for me)

Comment: the application is built in flex. I don't think jquery is used for flex. So, I'd say that no,jquery may not be loaded.
Is there any way I can load jquery from the firebug console itself.

Answer (score 3):

You must have forgotten to reference jquery before attempting to use it:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // here you can use $.post
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use script tags (or for that matter any tags) in firebug console.
However,I did try it,and it says that it "can't wrap XML objects".